# How do you find at what line a word is located in a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently working on a notepad that has a find option. When you type in a word it'll find it and highlight it. I got it working but I've reached a wall that I can't seem to pass with the method i'm currently using to do it. I'm currently splitting all the words in the textbox with ' ' and adding up the length of the words untill I find the inputted search term so I can see where exactly the found word was, so I can highlight it.

The problem I have now though, is that since i'm using split(' ') to get each word in the textbox, whenever the user adds a new line the split's return array will be "wordOnFirstLine\r\nwordOnSecondLine". So they will be counted as one word. 
What's another way I can find a word in the textbox and see where exactly it's located so I can highlight it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the string as

```
string splitstring = stringToSplit.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n', '\r' });
```

It'll give you an empty string in between all the '\n' and '\r' characters, but that fix may be closest to what you're currently doing.

Comment: YES! FINALLY! You don't know how long i've been breaking my head with this before I finally decided to ask! This solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the `GetLineFromCharIndex(int)` method. Passing in the index of the first character in your word should return its line number.

Answer (score 0):

You should not split all words with ' '. You can split the text by sentence('\n') and then use IndexOf for each sentence to find the word's occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Do not split anything. It is a waste of resource to create a potentially big array of strings.

Simply the IndexOf (with the appropriate case comparer) could give you the position of the first word in your whole textbox text

So supposing you are searching the word "answer" as a word delimited by a space before and after in your notepad text you write

```
int pos = 0;
string searchText = " answer ";
pos = myNotePad.Text.IndexOf(searchText, pos, StringComparison.CurrentCulture.IgnoreCase);
```

now to select the string

```
if(pos > 0)
{
    myNotePad.Text.SelectionStart = pos + 1;
    myNotePad.Text.SelectionLength = searchText.Length - 2;
}
```

And if you save the value of the variable pos you could also easily implement the Find Next functionality